# Miller: ofs="\n"?

Tags: csv, miller

Suppose I have:

```
cat file
"Field 1, Line 1",Field 2,"Field 3, Line 1"
"Field 1, Line 2",Field 2,"Field 3, Line 2"
```

With Miller, I want to produce:

```
"Field 1, Line 1"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 1"
"Field 1, Line 2"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 2"
```

I tried this:

```
mlr --csv -N  --ofs lf --quote-all cat file
```

Which produces no output.

As a workaround, I can do this:

```
mlr --csv -N  --ofs pipe --quote-all cat file | sed 's/"\|"/"\n"/g'
```

Or use ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'CSV.parse($<.read).flatten.each{|r| puts [r].to_csv(force_quotes: true)}' file
```

But it does feel that I should be able to just look at a csv file one field at a time (and ignore records) with Miller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape and enumerate:

```
mlr --csv --quote-all -N reshape -r ".*" -o a,b  input.csv
"1","Field 1, Line 1"
"2","Field 2"
"3","Field 3, Line 1"
"1","Field 1, Line 2"
"2","Field 2"
"3","Field 3, Line 2"
```

Then cut the first column (`cut -f b` keeps the second column named `b` in this case):

```
mlr --csv --quote-all -N reshape -r ".*" -o a,b then cut -f b input.csv
```

to get:

```
"Field 1, Line 1"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 1"
"Field 1, Line 2"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 2"
```

Comment: Add `--quote-all` and this works!

Comment: @dawg I didn't see that you wanted quotes everywhere, sorry. I corrected it. Don't accept that as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

While Miller treats `--ifs` and `--ofs` differently for the CSV format, not outputting any error message with `--ofs lf` feels like a bug...

As a workaround I would split the input records into multiple single-fielded ones:

```bash
mlr -c -N --quote-all filter -q 'for (k,v in $*) {emit {1:v}}'
```

```
"Field 1, Line 1"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 1"
"Field 1, Line 2"
"Field 2"
"Field 3, Line 2"
```